# Why does passing a string from C# to a C++ dll get NULL?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to connect a C# executable to a C++ dll. One of the methods of the dll receives a const char* and an int* (the first one specifying an input value, and the second one, an address to return a value):

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
  int setVal(long handle, const char* ptrVal, int* ptrRet);
```

The first thing this function does is to check whether ptrVal is null, and returns -1 if so.

On the other hand, the C# code invokes the dll as follows:

```
[DllImport(dllName,
           EntryPoint = "setVal",
           ExactSpelling = true,
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
           CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int setVal(long handle,
                                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str,
                                ref int ptrRes);
```

In the main function, I have

```
long handle = 0;
int result = 0;
int res = 0;
string str = "Hello World!";
result = setVal(handle, str, ref res);
```

When calling this function, I always receive a null pointer at the C side, which makes result equal to -1. I have tried different approaches when declaring the wrapper function, without success:

```
public static extern int setVal(long handle, 
                                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] [In] string str,
                                [Out] int ptrRes);
public static unsafe extern int setVal(long handle,
                                       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str,
                                       ref int ptrRes);
public static extern int setVal(long handle, 
                                StringBuilder sb,
                                ref int ptrRes); // also the unsafe version
public static extern int setVal(long handle,
                                byte[] value,
                                ref int ptrRes); // also the unsafe version
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and .NET framework 4.6.1.

Why am I always receiving NULL as the second argument (const char*) of the dll function?

Comment: See this regarding the first parameter : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/dotnet/managed-types-cpp-cli#dotnet - setting handle to 0 as C# long effectively passes a C++ long=0 & the address of the string to 0 (=null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of a google so this would be untested code but I can see it's something you haven't tried

declare external like so

```
[DllImport(dllName, EntryPoint = "setVal", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention, CallingConvention.Cdecl,CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int setVal(int handle, StringBuilder sb, ref int ptrRes);
```

and use it like so

```
int handle = 0;
int result = 0;
int res = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello World");
result = setVal(handle, sb, ref res);
```

Comment: Thanks to both xanatos and you I finally made it work! Key was int instead of long!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the `long handle` in C/C++ is `int handle` in C# both at 32 and 64 bits. You can check it by doing a `sizeof(long)` in C/C++. Windows is [LLP64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models).

Comment: Thank you so much! Using int was the key!